# JavaScript - Picking data with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xmlhttprequest, element

I'm having problems with my code, where I need to pick data with a JSON query from an API.

Here is the JSON body what I receive from the query:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "reservations": [
    {
      "id": "38199",
      "subject": "Koneiden vaihto",
      "modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T12:46:17",
      "startDate": "2017-06-21T08:00:00",
      "endDate": "2017-06-21T22:00:00",
      "resources": [
        {
          "id": "124",
          "type": "room",
          "code": "FRAMIF407",
          "parent": {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "building",
            "code": "FramiF",
            "name": "Frami F"
          },
          "name": "Frami F407 (atk 34)"
        }
      ],
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "30505",
      "subject": "Alumnitapahtuman etukäteisjärjestelyt",
      "modifiedDate": "2017-04-19T09:36:02",
      "startDate": "2017-06-21T08:00:00",
      "endDate": "2017-06-21T22:00:00",
      "resources": [
        {
          "id": "104",
          "type": "room",
          "code": "FRAMIF144",
          "parent": {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "building",
            "code": "FramiF",
            "name": "Frami F"
          },
          "name": "Frami F144 (lasipalatsi 120)"
        }
      ],
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "38864",
      "subject": "Koneiden vaihto/säilytystila",
      "modifiedDate": "2017-06-21T06:03:07",
      "startDate": "2017-06-21T08:00:00",
      "endDate": "2017-06-21T22:00:00",
      "resources": [
        {
          "id": "107",
          "type": "room",
          "code": "FRAMIF211",
          "parent": {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "building",
            "code": "FramiF",
            "name": "Frami F"
          },
          "name": "Frami F211 (fysioterapia/teoria)"
        }
      ],
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "38335",
      "subject": "Koneiden vaihto",
      "modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T12:48:32",
      "startDate": "2017-06-21T08:00:00",
      "endDate": "2017-06-21T22:00:00",
      "resources": [
        {
          "id": "127",
          "type": "room",
          "code": "FRAMIF410",
          "parent": {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "building",
            "code": "FramiF",
            "name": "Frami F"
          },
          "name": "Frami F410 (atk 34)"
        }
      ],
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "38426",
      "subject": "Koneiden vaihto",
      "modifiedDate": "2017-05-16T12:49:25",
      "startDate": "2017-06-21T08:00:00",
      "endDate": "2017-06-21T22:00:00",
      "resources": [
        {
          "id": "128",
          "type": "room",
          "code": "FRAMIF411",
          "parent": {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "building",
            "code": "FramiF",
            "name": "Frami F"
          },
          "name": "Frami F411 (atk 34)"
        }
      ],
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "43898",
      "subject": "Varattu plinttien varastointiin",
      "modifiedDate": "2017-06-12T08:54:31",
      "startDate": "2017-06-21T08:00:00",
      "endDate": "2017-06-21T22:00:00",
      "resources": [
        {
          "id": "106",
          "type": "room",
          "code": "FRAMIF210",
          "parent": {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "building",
            "code": "FramiF",
            "name": "Frami F"
          },
          "name": "Frami F210 (teoria 36)"
        }
      ],
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "38267",
      "subject": "Koneiden vaihto",
      "modifiedDate": "2017-06-21T06:03:07",
      "startDate": "2017-06-21T08:00:00",
      "endDate": "2017-06-21T22:00:00",
      "resources": [
        {
          "id": "126",
          "type": "room",
          "code": "FRAMIF409",
          "parent": {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "building",
            "code": "FramiF",
            "name": "Frami F"
          },
          "name": "Frami F409 (atk 34)"
        }
      ],
      "description": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to pick up the all the names from the body, which are for example :

`"Frami F407 (atk 34)"`, `"Frami F144 (lasipalatsi 120)"`,

`"Frami F211 (fysioterapia/teoria)"`, `"Frami F410 (atk 34)`

Here's how I process the data in order to get the names;

```
var jsonQuery = {
    "startDate": startDate,
    "endDate": endDate,
    "building": [building]
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);

        var rooms = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
            if (json.reservations[i].resources != null) {
               for (var j = 0; j < json.reservations[i].resources.length; j++) {
                   var reservation = json.reservations[i];
                   var resource = json.reservations[i].resources[j];

                   if (resource.type === "room") {
                       if (rooms.indexOf("code")) {
                           rooms.push(resource.name);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
};

xhr.open("POST", "URL", true, "API-key", "");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonQuery));
```

This is how it should work : https://jsfiddle.net/p474djan/3/

But the problem is, when I run it through `JSON.parse()` and check in the console log, it keeps the first two names (`"Frami F407 (atk 34)"` and `"Frami F144 (lasipalatsi 120)"`) but removes all the rest of the names. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is `if (rooms.indexOf("code")) {` supposed to be doing? Do you maybe mean `if (resource["code"]) {` instead?

Comment: (Or should that conditional perhaps be deleted altogether?)

Comment: What is the output of `console.dir(json);` , i.e. how many sets are in reservation?

Comment: Is the issue that `xhr.responseText` doesn't include the full JSON you expected to receive? (Does it not match what you've pasted here in your question?)

Comment: @smarx Yes the  `xhr.responseText ` only includes the first two  `"name:" ` elements;  `"name": "Frami F407 (atk 34)" ` and  `"name": "Frami F144 (lasipalatsi 120)" ` and the last names are just shown empty like;  `"name": "" `

Comment: @IlariM You said "Here is the JSON body what I receive from the query:". Are you now saying that's *not* the JSON you receive?

Comment: @smarx That is the JSON body in the API site I get with `jsonQuery` but after the `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` some of the names go empty.

Comment: So are you saying that `xhr.responseText` *does* include all the names, but the result of `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` does not?

Answer (score -1):

I am not able to find any issue on your code but here it is my suggestion you can achieve the same via underscore.js without any looping and so on

https://jsfiddle.net/p474djan/5/

```
document.getElementById("pageOne").innerHTML = _.pluck(_.flatten(_.pluck(json["reservations"], 'resources')), 'name').join("<br/>")
```

Please have a look in to this

Comment: While this suggested code improvement is perhaps reasonable, it doesn't address the problem in the question.

Comment: he/she doing many looping on their code, May chance to miss something. Shortly I look in to their jsfiddle and post a solution to get names without any looping and son on. At least they can try. why are you giving negative sign immediately @smarx

Comment: I downvoted because "answers" should address the question/problem that was posted. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to suggest improvements for already-working code.

Comment: If you want to post this as a comment, I think that's fine. It's just out of place as an answer.